# Modifying the Master Page & Page Layout HTML version VS the ASPX version

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, design-manager

One of the most conflicting thing for me in SharePoint 2013, is that master pages and page layouts have HTML and ASPX versions. and some articles and tutorial directly modify the ASPX files while other recommend not to touch the ASPX and do the modification to the HTML version where this changes will be reflected automatically inside the ASPX.

now in my case i have an Enterprise wiki site collection, and the enterprise wiki have a the default page layout named `EnterpriseWiki.aspx`.

now i am following these steps, to modify the built-in page layout:-

1. inside sharepoint designer 2013, or from "site setting >> web Designer Gallery >> master page and page layout", i download a copy of the built-in "EnteprriseWiki.aspx" to my PC, rename it (for example custom.aspx) , then upload it again to my site .
2. open the new file (custom.aspx) and do the modification inside it. such as adding new site columns, change the colors , etc.
3. publish the new custom.aspx page layout
4. set the custom.aspx as the default page layout inside my site collection.

Also i follow almost the same steps to modify the built-in seatle.master master page

So is my above appraoch considered valid. now as i mentioned some tutorials will follow my approach (for customizing Page Layouts & customizing master pages). while other will use the Design Manager as shown in this [link](http://sharedpointtips.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-page.html) to create html and aspx for the page layout and do the modification to the html version.
so can anyone adivce what are the main differences between these 2 approaches , and which one is recommended ?